# Grab data from certain, variable number of rows in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have searched and searched for a solution - but then I don't really know where to begin with this one. May not have been the most effective search.

I have a spreadsheet that chronologically lays out tasks with responsible peoples' initials next to them (a leader and a backup). I am to make a new worksheet that displays this data differently and is person-based.

Is there a way to have Excel seek out which rows have given initials (initials are in a cell of their own in the source) - in either the leader or backup cells - and then insert a formula like the below for those rows? This example grabs a bunch of text from different cells and puts it together (AB+CD, this place - doing this) in a different layout I'm using. What I need Excel to do is fill in the row (30, below):

='AUDSCHED-COPY'!I30&"+"&'AUDSCHED-COPY'!J30&", "&'AUDSCHED-COPY'!D30&" - "& 'AUDSCHED-COPY'!E30

I'd like to have a little section for each person, one on top of the other. Will Excel be able to adjust the whole sheet based on the number of times a person's initials occur on the other sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This involves quite a lot of guesswork as to what you want to achieve, but should at least be a start.

Apply your formula to all rows in existing sheet.

1. Copy all rows, except label row, immediately below existing data.
2. Move copied part of `ColumnJ` to a blank column, say `Y`, (same rows).
3. Move copied part of `ColumnI` to a blank column, say `Z`, (same rows).
4. Move relevant rows of `ColumnsY and Z` to `ColumnsI and J`.
5. Create pivot table in new sheet from `ColumnsI to K` of existing
   sheet, with labels from `ColumnI` and `ColumnJ` for Row Labels.
6. Sort pivot rows alphabetically.

To add new task, overwrite first copied row, then copy all rows [from immediately below label row to overwritten row] over rows below overwritten row and refresh pivot table.

Not elegant but if this ‘manual’ approach achieves the result you want then you have a basis for a code solution.